# A linear/Lie algebra problem

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex linear Lie algebra of dimension $n$. If there exists a basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\begin{equation}\sum_{i=1}^n[e_i,\bar{e_i}^T]=0,\end{equation}$ what can we say about $\mathfrak{g}$? Is it true that every semisimple $\mathfrak{g}$ has this property?
Thanks!

Comment: What is $\bar{e_i}^T$?

Comment: @abx: That is the conjugate transpose of $e_i$.

Comment: “conjugate transpose” is not something that makes sense in an abstract Lie algebra.  So I suppose you are implicitly assuming that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a complex Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(N,\mathbb{C})$ for some $N$?

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill: that is exactly what I mean by a linear Lie algebra.

Comment: My apologies.  I read “complex linear” as “complex-linear”, meaning simply “complex”.  Now I understand the question; but have to think about an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This condition seems awkward from a Lie algebra point of view. Perhaps you could explain where it arises from?

A few observations:
-A sufficient condition is to have a basis of normal matrices. I believe one can construct a basis of normal matrices for the classical complex lie algebras. I am not sure about the exceptional lie algebras.

-This condition is closed under direct sums, so you can use this to build semisimple lie algebras

-A (silly) example of a lie algebra where this condition doesn't hold is just the one dimensional lie algebra spanned by the matrix $E = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ since $E E^* - E^* E = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$.